# Obstacles added through service call (/apply_planning_scene) not reflected in PlanningSceneMonitor

Tags: moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Setup:

```
std::unique_ptr<robot_model_loader::RobotModelLoader> ur10_model_loader = std::make_unique<robot_model_loader::RobotModelLoader>("robot_description");
robot_model::RobotModelPtr ur10_kinematic_model = ur10_model_loader -> getModel();

planning_scene_monitor::PlanningSceneMonitorPtr ur10_planning_scene_monitor;
ur10_planning_scene_monitor = planning_scene_monitor::PlanningSceneMonitorPtr(new planning_scene_monitor::PlanningSceneMonitor("robot_description"));
ur10_planning_scene_monitor -> startSceneMonitor();
ur10_planning_scene_monitor -> startWorldGeometryMonitor();
ur10_planning_scene_monitor -> startStateMonitor();
ur10_planning_pipeline = std::make_shared<planning_pipeline::PlanningPipeline>
                         (planning_pipeline::PlanningPipeline(ur10_kinematic_model, nodeHandle, "planning_plugin", "request_adapters"));
robot_model::JointModelGroup* manipulator_joint_model_group = ur10_kinematic_model -> getJointModelGroup(MANIPULATOR_JOINT_GROUP);
```

I add an obstacle into the scene with the following:

```
moveit_msgs::PlanningScene planning_scene_msg;
{// scope
    planning_scene_monitor::LockedPlanningSceneRO planning_sceneRO (ur10_planning_scene_monitor);
    planning_sceneRO -> getPlanningSceneMsg(planning_scene_msg);
}// scope

planning_scene_msg.world.collision_objects.clear();

planning_scene_msg.world.collision_objects.push_back(robot_workspace); // where robot_workspace has been filled with obstacles
planning_scene_msg.is_diff = true;
planning_scene_msg.robot_state.is_diff = true;

ros::ServiceClient update_planning_scene_service_client = nodeHandle.serviceClient<moveit_msgs::ApplyPlanningScene>("apply_planning_scene");
moveit_msgs::ApplyPlanningScene apply_scene_msg;
apply_scene_msg.request.scene = planning_scene_msg;
update_planning_scene_service_client.call(apply_scene_msg)
```

I can verify that the obstacle is visible in rviz under "Scene Geometry".

I invoke the planner as follows

```
    planning_scene_monitor::LockedPlanningSceneRO lscene(ur10_planning_scene_monitor);
    ur10_planning_pipeline -> generatePlan(lscene, motion_request, motion_response);
```

However, the generated trajectory just passes through the obstacle.

----------------------------------- UPDATE 1 ------------------------------------------

After much digging and referring to `moveit/moveit_ros/move_group/src/default_capabilities/move_action_capability.cpp`, changing

```
ur10_planning_pipeline -> generatePlan(lscene, motion_request, motion_response);
```

to

```
ur10_planning_pipeline -> generatePlan(lscene->diff(planning_scene_msg), motion_request, motion_response);
```

solves the problem.  However, I don't believe that is the correct way to fix this.

Further digging revealed that the `lscene` from

```
planning_scene_monitor::LockedPlanningSceneRO lscene(ur10_planning_scene_monitor);
```

does not get updated with the obstacle, i.e.

```
    moveit_msgs::PlanningScene tmp;
    lscene->getPlanningSceneMsg(tmp);
    ROS_INFO("collision objects: %ld", tmp.world.collision_objects.size());
```

Still gives 0 obstacles.

Shouldn't the PlanningSceneMonitor be automatically updated when the `/apply_planning_scene` service is called?

Using

```
ur10_planning_scene_monitor->monitorDiffs(true)
```

or

```
ur10_planning_scene_monitor->startPublishingPlanningScene(planning_scene_monitor::PlanningSceneMonitor::UPDATE_SCENE);
```

or

```
ur10_planning_scene_monitor->startPublishingPlanningScene(planning_scene_monitor::PlanningSceneMonitor::UPDATE_SCENE, "/move_group/monitored_planning_scene");
```

or

```
ur10_planning_scene_monitor -> startSceneMonitor("/move_group/monitored_planning_scene");
```

does not solve the problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/352589/obstacles-added-through-service-call-(/apply_planning_scene)-not-reflected-in-planningscenemonitor/) by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1083 on 2020-05-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-19**:
This Q&A seems related: #q352656.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears that changing

```
ur10_planning_scene_monitor -> startSceneMonitor();
```

to

```
ur10_planning_scene_monitor -> startSceneMonitor("/move_group/monitored_planning_scene");
```

as well as adding a 2 second delay between

```
update_planning_scene_service_client.call(apply_scene_msg)
```

and

```
planning_scene_monitor::LockedPlanningSceneRO lscene(ur10_planning_scene_monitor);
```

allows me to reliably get an `lscene` that contains the collision object.

This seems counter to what [the tutorial](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/planning_scene_ros_api/planning_scene_ros_api_tutorial.html#interlude-synchronous-vs-asynchronous-updates) mentions about service call being synchronous (blocks until diff is applied).  Though it may refer to blocking until the diff is applied only to `move_group`'s `PlanningSceneMonitor`, and not every listening `PlanningSceneMonitor`

The Q&A for this behavior can be found here: https://answers.ros.org/question/352721/applying-scene-changes-through-service-call-does-not-block-until-changes-are-applied/

---

Originally posted by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) with karma: 1083 on 2020-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0